# On a suggested edit, what is indicated by a tag being both red and green?

Tags: support, bug, tags, suggested-edits

I recently reviewed a suggested edit and this is what I saw:

[image]

As you can see, [spells](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/spells) appears twice, once as though it were removed, and once as though it were added. Is this a bug? What does this mean?

Comment: I did nothing to the spells tag.  I only added "wish".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### That's not a suggested edit thing, that's a tag order thing

Main meta Q on this: [Diff shows tag being added and removed in the same revision](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/56216/681403)

The answer to which explains:

> The tagging system automatically sorts tags based on how many times they're used. However, this is relatively new, so when a new edit is processed for an old post, the system sees the sort as a delete and re-insert because it is now in a new position.

In the time since that question was last edited, we have gotten net more [spells](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/spells) questions than [pathfinder-1e](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pathfinder-1e) questions, so the former is now sorted first, unfortunately.